# How to retrieve user information after login with RESTful services

Tags: rest, web-services, system-design

What should be the standard approach for getting user information after login ?

- POST request to validate user/password and retrieve information on response
- POST request to validate user/password followed by GET request to retrieve information?

As far as I understand, GET should be the preferred one to retrieve data, but it seems burdensome to performe two requests; at the same time, it feels weird to get data back on POST response. Which should be preferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 2 cents:) if you really want to follow REST Paradigm then you should use standard http method as GET. Although an overloaded POST might do the job however it’s not following the standard.

In SOAP world everything is POST and you can do a lot of funky stuff however in REST world there is a standard on what method used for what purpose ideally.

Comment: That sounds right, I think there won't be a middle-ground on this :)